# How to filter elements based on substring of multiple name using jquery, I tried below but not worked:

Tags: jquery, performance, jquery-ui, jquery-plugins

I tried below thing but not worked:

```
$( "input[id][name*='Address.Line1'][name*='Address.Line2'][name*='Address.City'][name*='Address.StatesList'][name*='Address.CountryList'][name*='Address.PostalCode']")
```

I need all elements based on "OR" condition.

Please help.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Use [comma separated multiple selectors](https://api.jquery.com/multiple-selector/) for that.

```
$("input[id][name*='Address.Line1'],input[id][name*='Address.Line2'],input[id][name*='Address.City'],input[id][name*='Address.StatesList'],input[id][name*='Address.CountryList'],input[id][name*='Address.PostalCode']")
```

Use [`filter()`](https://api.jquery.com/filter/) method to make it more readable.

```
$( "input[id]").filter("[name*='Address.Line1'],[name*='Address.Line2'],[name*='Address.City'],[name*='Address.StatesList'],[name*='Address.CountryList'],[name*='Address.PostalCode']");
```

Comment: @VatanSoni : glad to help you :)